# Basic SQL SUM and JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, request, sum

I am a bit disoriented about SQL and its associations.
I have two tables **"hotel"** and **"room"**.

In my **room** table I have a field called **"hotel_id"**, **"capacity"** and **"book"**
and in my **hotel** table I have a field **"name"**.

My **"book"** field is a boolean, so if it's **"0"** it means it is free, and if it is **"1"** it is booked.

My main goal is to show the name of the hotel and the free capacity based on free rooms, like this:

***name***

**COSTA DEL SOL**

***capacity***

**35**

(it is meant to be a table with two column)

So I wrote this to begin with:

```
SELECT * FROM room WHERE book = "0";
```

which gives me all free rooms.

Then I wrote this:

```
SELECT hotel_id, SUM(capacity) FROM room WHERE book = "0" GROUP BY hotel_id;
```

which gives me all capacity of all hotel with their ID's

And then I wrote:

```
SELECT name, hotel_id FROM hotel INNER JOIN room ON hotel.id = room.hotel_id GROUP BY name;
```

which gives me hotel names and their ID's.

So I'm a bit lost by combining the request of **sum** and **join**. I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

I tried this but didn't worked out:

```
SELECT name, hotel_id, sum(capacity) AS hotelcapacity FROM hotel
INNER JOIN room ON hotel.id = room.hotel_id GROUP BY hotelcapacity;
```

If anyone could help me out, it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought it was on the server side, didn't mean to spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you group on hotel capacity instead of id and name like:

```
SELECT h.name, r.hotel_id, sum(r.capacity) AS hotelcapacity 
FROM hotel h INNER JOIN room r
ON h.id = r.hotel_id 
GROUP BY h.name, r.hotel_id
```

To get capacity of free rooms, you would use query as below:

```
SELECT h.name, r.hotel_id, sum(r.capacity) AS hotelcapacity 
FROM hotel h INNER JOIN room r
ON h.id = r.hotel_id 
WHERE r.book = "0" 
GROUP BY h.name, r.hotel_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I get this error:
**ERROR 1052 (23000): Column 'capacity' in field list is ambiguous**

Comment: Probably you have capacity in both hotel as well as room table. Use the alias as above.

Comment: It works! :) but what does mean **hotel h** and **room r** why is the **h** and **r** are alone?
Also it works without callin back **hotelcapacity**. why is that? should **hotelcapacity** is useless?

Answer (score 2):

You need to group by the hotel name, not the capacity.  You can also exclude the hotel id from your query.

Something like:

```
SELECT name, SUM(capacity) AS hotelcapacity 
FROM hotel
INNER JOIN room ON hotel.id = room.hotel_id 
GROUP BY name;
```

If you require the hotel id in the query, then you do so by adding it to the group by:

```
SELECT name, hotel_id, SUM(capacity) AS hotelcapacity 
FROM hotel
INNER JOIN room ON hotel.id = room.hotel_id 
GROUP BY name, hotel_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your final query needs to aggregate by the right columns:

```
SELECT h.name, r.hotel_id, sum(r.capacity) AS hotelcapacity
FROM hotel h LEFT JOIN
     room r
     ON h.id = r.hotel_id
     WHERE r.book = "0"
GROUP BY h.name, r.hotel_id;
```

I also changed the `JOIN` to a left join, just in case some hotels have no rooms in the `room` table.

I also introduced table aliases.  You should get in the habit of using these.  Abbreviations for the table names are the best.  And, you should use the table alias when referencing columns (both to clarify the code and to prevent compiler errors).

Comment: Thanks for the help but I get this error: **ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'h.hotel_id' in 'field list'**

Comment: Okay your solution works fine :) I changed the **h.hotel_id** to **r.hotel_id** because it was in my room table. I will validate your answer as the good one because it seem more simple, but can you explain me why you putted **hotel h* and **room r** ? whats does it stand for? why the **h** and the **r** are alone?